# Retrofit2 request gives SocketTimeoutException:

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

When I try request service to use Retrofit2 in android, server response gives below error, **exception : connect timed outjava.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at** why I got socketTimeout exception in send Request?

request service: http://182.20.1.14:2020/api/MainAppExternal/UpdateFcmId

```
private Retrofit retrofit(String url, boolean addLogInterceptor, int timeout) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url).client(getOkHttpClient(addLogInterceptor, timeout))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(LocalGsonBuilder.getInstance().getGson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(boolean addLogInterceptor, int timeout) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    setupInterceptor(httpClient, addLogInterceptor);
    setupTimeout(httpClient, timeout);

    return httpClient.build();
}

private void setupInterceptor(OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient, boolean addLogInterceptor) {
    if (addLogInterceptor) {
        httpClient.addInterceptor(new ConnectionInterceptor());
    }
}
```

exception : connect timed outjava.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:341) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:650) at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:63) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:223)    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)  at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)  at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at com.dgpays.mpos.common.common.ConnectionInterceptor.intercept(ConnectionInterceptor.java:84) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)  at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267) at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34) at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267) at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)   at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: I cannot reach to the URL . Is the API url working fine ?

Comment: yes, you right, url was wrong, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Add  `getOkHttpClient` function like this.

```
private OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(boolean addLogInterceptor, int timeout) {
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
            connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    setupInterceptor(httpClient, addLogInterceptor);
    return httpClient.build();
}
```

Comment: it gives same exception